# One SKU, multiple products in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

In my store, I sell products for automobiles. My products fit many vehicles and I would like to display them separately.  Example:

Sku 808-99-2000 fits Honda, Acura, Toyota, Scion and Lexus.  I would like to display this on part as 5 different products in my one store as:

DBW for Honda
DBW for Acura
Etc.

As opposed to one long-winded product called: DBW for Honda/Acura/Toyota...

Answer (score 1):

The SKU has to be unique. If you want different product names, you need different products => different SKUs. I would recommend throwing an extra -HONDA, -ACURA, etc suffix on the base SKU to create unique variants.

Otherwise, you could leave the car model out of the product name and put that info into some other info field that is displayed on the product details page (and is perhaps filterable as a multiselect).